# Access IIS 7.5 Express started by Visual Studio 2010 from VMWare Guest

Tags: visual-studio, vmware, iis-express

I have VS2010sp1 I have developed a MVC 3 site with C#, jQuery etc. When I develop I use IIS Express. A client now wants me to test the site from Internet Explorer 7 on a Windows XP machine. 
I have a XP machine with with IE7 in a virtual machine running on VMWare. The VMWare machine network adapter is set to bridged.
I am running VS2010, IIS Express and VMWare workstation 8 on the same machine (A 64 bit Windows 7 Ultimate) . I seem to be able to access the host. I can ping the name of the host machine and it answers with correct ip address and it is alive. 
How should I configure IIS Express and the virtual machine so I can access my website from the IE7 that is running in the virtual machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is old but just for reference if anyone wants an answer.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

I think the new IIS Express 8 can be configured in a similar manner.

*Edit*:   **`applicationHost.config`** for detailed configuration steps follow the URL^

```
<site name="MvcApplication18" id="39">
  <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
     <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\users\scottha\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication18\MvcApplication18" />
  </application>
  <bindings>
    <binding protocol="http"  bindingInformation="*:15408:localhost" />
    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44302:localhost" />
    <binding protocol="http"  bindingInformation="*:80:hanselman-w500" />
    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:hanselman-w500" />
  </bindings>
</site>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks. I am new and didn't think of that. I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried configuring IIS to host your website with a the local ip, perhaps with the port number set to 80, then just call up the page in your browser on the VM. If it is on port 80 i think you shouldn't need to add the port number when typing the address in the browser.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866547/binding-iis-express-to-an-ip-address) for configuring IIS express