# Bad Request - Invalid Hostname ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I've got an ASP.NET MVC 4 application, which I can browse locally

```
http://localhost:portnr/SomeController
```

When I try to browse it from another computer in the same network, or just by local ip, I get "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname"

```
http://192.168.0.x:portnr/SomeController
```

I dont get the same error if I specify an invalid portnr, so I guess the error message is from asp.net itself.
I'm trying to browse the site from my IPhone.

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but anyway, better take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866547/binding-iis-express-to-an-ip-address

Comment: I know this is a little bit old, but anyway, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866547/binding-iis-express-to-an-ip-address

Comment: It's 7 years old... I'm past this issue ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port is an internal dev server port. You will need to use a tool like SPI Port Forward to forward your local port externally outside your local computer. 
Here is a link that shows you how the tool works,

http://vishnuvalentino.com/download/spi-port-forward-redirection-for-windows-to-another-port-ip-address/