# How to view a asp.net mvc web application in another computer based on its IP address?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I wan to open my asp.net mvc website in another PC by using: "http://163.155.xxx.xxx:49397"
I added these codes in my iis applicationhost.config file, but this does not work, any idea?

```
<site name="PerfM" id="3">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="PerfM">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012  
 \Projects\PerfM\PerfM" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
          <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:49397:163.155.xxx.xxx" />
        </bindings>     
       </site>
```

Comment: basically, I want to open my mvc web site in another PC by this  URL:http://163.155.94.115:49397, any idea how to make it working?

Answer (score 0):

I think your bindings may need to be configured quite right.

```
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:49397:" />
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="163.155.94.115:49397:" />
```

Try the above. If not maybe try modifying it ussing IIS manager.

You should also disable windows fire wall or open port 49397 for access via HTTP. By default this port will be blocked.

[How to turn windows fire wall on and off.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/turn-windows-firewall-on-off#turn-windows-firewall-on-off=windows-7) I suggest you turn off the fire wall first. That will eliminate it as a potential problem. Once you have the site working from another computer you can try to turn it back on and open a port. [Here are some instructions on how to open a port.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: I will try your solution, but I was following this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866547/binding-iis-express-to-an-ip-address

Comment: Your link suggests that the format for binding protocol is <ip-address>:<port>:<host-name> so then the above should be correct in your listing you had IP address in the host name field. Good luck getting it going.

Comment: Hope your solution will be working, I will try it later and let you know the result. by the way, how to "disable windows fire wall or open port 49397 for access via HTTP" ?

Comment: I tried it, it does not work Even my primary machine, error message related to the two paths (I used "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PerfM\PerfM" /> in the applicationhost.config file. But I removed it , it still not working, I even remove everthiing I added in applicationhost.config file,then when I launch my apps in original machine, i got: "A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly, In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project"

Comment: You need to right lick on your web site project and select set as StartUp Project. That should fix the error you are getting.

Comment: Probably need to have a look at your applicationhost.config file once you get your site back up. If you can get it working from the local machine then make sure your fire wall is down and try it from another machine. Probably wouldn't hurt to double check your IP either and that you can access the sight using the IP from the local machine. IF it's working on the local machine there really shouldn't be that much to do to get it going over the network. Just the binding and the fire wall.

Comment: set as StartUp Project is working fine now,I double checked it, my id address is correct, the thing is it is not working in my local machine by using IP address.