# accessing windows localhost from a mac

Tags: windows, macos, virtual

I have parallels installed on my mac and I have installed windows 8 as a virtual machine. I am able to run an application running on the mac localhost in windows 8 but now I would like to run a .net app on the mac (i.e. `localhost:50055`). I have read numerous solutions but none is working for me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I just bashed my head against this for a couple of hours too and I think, in the end, the piece I was missing was turning off Windows 8's firewall.

This accepted solution is what clued me into turning off my firewall, as soon as I did that it worked.
[Access Parallels Windows localhost from Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673595/access-parallels-windows-localhost-from-mac)

You'll probably have to "enable" anonymous authentication in Authentication setting in IIS Manager" too according to Matt Gibson's solution.

What I ended up doing:

- Found the VM's ip address by pulling up the command prompt and typing ipconfig
- Updated my Mac's host file by adding the VM's ip address (in my case it was 10.211.55.3)
- Checked Parallels VM Setting -> Configure -> Hardware was set to Shared Network
- Windows Firewall - turned off for Private Network Settings (Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall\Customize Settings)
- Checked IIS Authentication -> Anonymous Authentication is Enabled

This worked for me, hopefully it'll work for you too.