# How to connect to local database on virtual machine from Mac? (Parallels)

Tags: python, mysql, localhost, parallels

I'm writing a python script on Jupyter notebook on my Mac OS, and I'm trying to connect to a local DB that is located on my Parallels Windows operating system that is running from my external hard drive.

I've tried the following code:

```
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import codecs
import datetime
import pytz
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

params = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};' 'SERVER=local;' 'DATABASE=Totepro;'

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(params)
db = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s' % params)

def get_new_race_data():
    sql_get_data = '''
    SELECT * FROM RaceRowReport
    WHERE RaceKey = cur_race_key
    '''

new_race_data = pd.read_sql_query(sql_get_data, db)
return new_race_data

get_new_race_data()
```

This is the output:

```
OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

I have also tried the following in terms of adjusting the connection string:

```
SERVER=10.211.55.3
```

However I still got the same issue. I've turned off the firewall from windows, but still nothing. 
..

Then I tried:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='10.211.55.3',
                                         database='Totepro')
```

and now I find myself with the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ''@'localmac' (using password: NO)
```

Any assistance would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I assume you're trying to connect to MS SQL Server, though your question has contradictory information - parts of it refer to MSSQL, while other parts mention MySQL.*

First you need to establish network connectivity with the guest. [Access Parallels Windows localhost from Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673595/access-parallels-windows-localhost-from-mac) might be helpful with that. I'm guessing that while you try to use `SERVER=local`, you don't actually have `local` mapped to the guest VM. Once you ensure the guest VM uses "Shared networking" and find its public IP address (referred to as YOUR_VM_IP_ADDRESS from now on), check that you can ping it with

```
ping YOUR_VM_IP_ADDRESS
```

Then check that you can access the SQL Server's port (the default is 1433), using

```
nc -v YOUR_VM_IP_ADDRESS 1433
# -- or --
telnet YOUR_VM_IP_ADDRESS 1433
# shouldn't say "connection refused"
```

Ensure that you can connect using `sqlcmd` (note that Windows authentication won't work when connecting from the macOS machine, you have to use login/password):

```
sqlcmd -S YOUR_VM_IP_ADDRESS -U username -P password
```

After the above tests succeed, you have a chance of coming up with the correct connection string and establishing the SQLAlchemy connection. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41729710/1026) might help with that.

Comment: "telnet" is no longer available by default since High Sierra, so if you need telnet, you need to install telnet by yourself since telnet is not secured. You can use "nc" instead.